# setup letsencrypt ClusterIssuer with terraform

Tags: ssl, kubernetes, terraform, cert-manager

i have a terraform config that create a kubernetes(GKE) on GCP, install ingress and cert-manager using Helm.
the only part missing is the letsencrypt ClusterIssuer (when i deploy the letsencrypt.yaml manually all works fine).

my Terraform config:

```
# provider
provider "kubernetes" {
  host                   = google_container_cluster.runners.endpoint
  cluster_ca_certificate = base64decode(google_container_cluster.runners.master_auth.0.cluster_ca_certificate)
  token                  = data.google_client_config.current.access_token
}

provider "helm" {
  kubernetes {
      host                   = google_container_cluster.runners.endpoint
      cluster_ca_certificate = base64decode(google_container_cluster.runners.master_auth.0.cluster_ca_certificate)
      token                  = data.google_client_config.current.access_token
  }
}

# create namespace for ingress controller
resource "kubernetes_namespace" "ingress" {
  metadata {
    name = "ingress"
  }
}
# deploy ingress controller
resource "helm_release" "ingress" {
  name       = "ingress"
  namespace = kubernetes_namespace.ingress.metadata[0].name

  repository = "https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx"
  chart      = "ingress-nginx"

  values = [
    "${file("./helm_values/ingress.yaml")}"
  ]
  set {
    name  = "controller.service.loadBalancerIP"
    value = google_compute_address.net_runner.address
  }
}

#create namespace for cert mananger
resource "kubernetes_namespace" "cert" {
  metadata {
    name = "cert-manager"
  }
}

#deploy cert maanger
resource "helm_release" "cert" {
  name       = "cert-manager"
  namespace = kubernetes_namespace.cert.metadata[0].name
  repository = "https://charts.jetstack.io"
  chart      = "cert-manager"
  depends_on = ["helm_release.ingress"]
  set {
    name  = "version"
    value = "v1.4.0"
  }
  set {
    name  = "installCRDs"
    value = "true"
  }
}
```

my letsencrypt.yaml:

```
apiVersion: cert-manager.io/v1
kind: ClusterIssuer
metadata:
  name: letsencrypt-prod
spec:
  acme:
    email: example@example.com
    server: https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory
    privateKeySecretRef:
      name: letsencrypt-prod
    solvers:
    - http01:
        ingress:
          class: nginx
```

any idea how to deploy the ClusterIssuer using terraform?

Answer (score 7):

You can apply the directly **YAML** file to the cluster

```
provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = <<EOT
cat <<EOF | kubectl --server=${aws_eks_cluster.demo.endpoint} --insecure-skip-tls-verify=true --token=${data.aws_eks_cluster_auth.demo.token} create -f -
apiVersion: certmanager.k8s.io/v1alpha1
kind: ClusterIssuer
metadata:
  name: lets-encrypt
spec:
  acme:
    server: https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory
    email: mymail@gmail.com
    privateKeySecretRef:
      name: letsencrypt
    http01: {}
EOF
EOT
  }
```

or else you can also use the **TF** **provider** to apply the **YAML** file

https://registry.terraform.io/providers/gavinbunney/kubectl/latest/docs#installation

**update** :

if you have not set up the Kubernetes provider to **authenticate** you can use from :
https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/kubernetes/latest/docs

```
provider "kubernetes" {
  config_path    = "~/.kube/config"
  config_context = "my-context"
}

resource "kubernetes_namespace" "example" {
  metadata {
    name = "my-first-namespace"
  }
}
```

Comment: before I submit a question, I tried the local-exec and i got an error with authentication to my cluster.
for now, i created a helm chart and used the helm provider.

Comment: you can also use the Kubernetes to authenticate instead of helm provider, https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/kubernetes/latest/docs...updated same in answer also

Comment: any update on this ? please feel free to mark the question as accepted if any of below resolves your issues.

Answer (score 5):

I recently did this most successfully using the Terraform tool [tfk8s](https://github.com/jrhouston/tfk8s) to migrate yaml files. You can also use [Terraform yamldecode.](https://www.terraform.io/language/functions/yamldecode)

1. Test your yaml files and make sure they are working exactly like you want before using the tool.
2. Using tfk8s, run `tfk8s cluster-issuer.yaml -o cluster-issuer.tf` This will create a working `kubernetes_manifest` resource.

Here is an example of my entire terraform script that installs it along with CRDs and ClusterIssuer.

```
resource "helm_release" "cert-manager" {
  name       = "cert-manager"
  repository = "https://charts.jetstack.io"
  chart      = "cert-manager"
  version    = "1.7.1"

  namespace        = "cert-manager"
  create_namespace = true

  #values = [file("cert-manager-values.yaml")]

  set {
    name  = "installCRDs"
    value = "true"
  }

}

resource "kubernetes_manifest" "clusterissuer_letsencrypt_prod" {
  manifest = {
    "apiVersion" = "cert-manager.io/v1"
    "kind" = "ClusterIssuer"
    "metadata" = {
      "name" = "letsencrypt-prod"
    }
    "spec" = {
      "acme" = {
        "email" = "myemail@email.com"
        "privateKeySecretRef" = {
          "name" = "letsencrypt-prod"
        }
        "server" = "https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory"
        "solvers" = [
          {
            "http01" = {
              "ingress" = {
                "class" = "nginx"
              }
            }
          },
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**NOTE** This tool creates a resource type `kubernetes_manifest`, and Terraform docs state that it's not a [stable resource to use with an initial `apply` command](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/kubernetes/latest/docs/resources/manifest#before-you-use-this-resource). In other words, create the cluster, etc first, then add the files and apply again. Otherwise, you need to manually migrate each kubernetes_manifest into its own dedicated resource type (deployment, service, etc).

Comment: If CRDs are not already installed, it will complain about `no matches for kind "ClusterIssuer" in group "cert-manager.io"`

Comment: True, an easy way to overcome that, and the way I chose to handle it, is add `depends_on = [helm_release.cert-manager]`. There are other ways to create dependency as well. With that manifest now technically being HCL referencing helm_release.cert-manager.<somevalue> would also work, but in my designs that's not always the case. Ultimately I turned it into its own module using this as a starting point: https://github.com/terraform-iaac/terraform-kubernetes-cert-manager